Add KUnit Tests to external Module for linux kernel
I'm trying to add kunit tests to an external kernel module which is build out-of-tree.
The kernel against which I am building is version 6.6.33, and I do cross compile for arm64.
The normal build (without tests) of my module "mymod" is working fine.
I added the following test code in a file mymod_test.c
#include <kunit/test.h>

/* Define the test cases. */

static void mymod_add_test_basic(struct kunit *test) {
  KUNIT_EXPECT_EQ(test, 1, 1); //test should be ok
}

static void mymod_test_failure(struct kunit *test) {
  KUNIT_FAIL(test, "This test never passes.");
}

static struct kunit_case mymod_test_cases[] = {
    KUNIT_CASE(mymod_add_test_basic),
    KUNIT_CASE(mymod_test_failure),
    {}};

static struct kunit_suite mymod_test_suite = {
    .name = "mymod",
    .test_cases = mymod_test_cases,
};
kunit_test_suite(mymod_test_suite);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

and I added the new source file to the makefile like that:
obj-m += mymod.o
mymod-objs += mymod_test.o
PWD := $(CURDIR) 

# Kernel sources
KDIR := $(CURDIR)/../linux

all: 
        make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE)   -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean


but it gives me a error during compile:
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/alex/mymod'
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-   -C /home/alex/mymod/../linux M=/home/alex/mymod  modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/alex/linux'
  CC [M]  /home/alex/mymod/mymod_test.o
  LD [M]  /home/alex/mymod/mymod.o
  MODPOST /home/alex/mymod/Module.symvers
ERROR: modpost: "__kunit_do_failed_assertion" [/home/alex/mymod/mymod.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "kunit_fail_assert_format" [/home/alex/mymod/mymod.ko] undefined!
make[4]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:145: /home/alex/mymod/Module.symvers] Error 1
make[3]: *** [/home/alex/linux/Makefile:1874: modpost] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/linux'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/alex/mymod'
make: *** [Makefile:15: all] Error 2

I also tried the advice given here:
How to use KUnit to test external modules?
and refactored the makefile like so:
obj-m += mymod.o mymod_test.o
...

But this leads to the same error.
Now I am a little bit lost on what I could try further.
Any hints as to what I am doing wrong here would be fantastic. I could not find more information on building kunit tests for external modules. All the documentation refers to build in-tree modules with unit tests, as far as I understood.

Does your kernel has KUNIT configuration option enabled ('y' or 'm')? Exactly that option is responsible for building a "library" which defines unit testing functions.

Thanks to tsyvarev for pointing me in the right direction. The Problem was the missing KUNIT enable in the Kernel Config.
Solved with
...
CONFIG_KUNIT=y
...

in kernel configuration.
